# While Working with Mininet, what should be started first the POX controller or Mininet and why?

Tags: networking, mininet, sdn, pox

While working with Mininet, what should be started first: the POX controller or Mininet and why?

Comment: I would guess the controller, so that mininet is able to establish a connection when you `start` the network.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried both options and each seems to work. I'd prefer starting with the controller so that Mininet will be ready to go. If you start with Mininet instead, you will not have connectivity (e.g. Pingall would fail) until the POX controller is running.